# c++ Boost if .extension() == "" this would mean this file is a folder?

Tags: c++, boost

I just want to confirm that this would be a good method to allow me to only work only on folders, as i can see a way to just look for folder rather that files and folders .

```
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator iterator(string("."));
for (; iterator != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++iterator)
{
    if ((iterator->path().extension()) == "") { 
        cout << (iterator->path().stem()) <<   endl; 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Files can exist without any extension, so this won't work.

Have a look at [`boost::filesystem::is_directory`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#is_directory).

---

By the way, Boost.Filesystem library was [merged into C++17 standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). So, if your compiler supports C++17, consider using the standard library for filesystem operations.

Comment: Thank you, this help a lot, am just getting to grip with boost and c++ ,

Comment: is there a way to iterator only for folders / directory in boost  could i do something like :  directory_iterator it{is_directory(p)};

Comment: @KnotwoodV I doubt such a thing exists in boost::filesystem. What's wrong with iterating using a `directory_iterator` and checking for `is_directory(it->status())`?

Comment: oh nothing, just though it would be smart to exclude any unwanted files from the outset rather than from within the iterator.

Comment: @KnotwoodV If you are concerned about performance, I doubt it would make any difference - most low-level filesystem API's don't have the corresponding options, and the filesystems themselves are not optimized for that. From the code quality point of view, you could use a `filter_iterator` from Boost: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/filter.html

Comment: thank you, you have given me quite a lot to think about ! , much appreciated thanks again

Comment: @KnotwoodV Always happy to help.